# Spotify Web API not detecting body of POST request

Tags: python, post, request, spotify

I'm currently working on an app, one functionality of it being that it can add songs to the user's queue. I'm using the Spotify API for this, and this is my code to do so:

```
async def request():
    ...
    uri = "spotify:track:5QO79kh1waicV47BqGRL3g" # temporary, can change later on
    header = {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        'Authorization': "{} {}".format(TOKEN_TYPE, ACCESS_TOKEN)}
    data = {'uri': uri}
    resp = requests.post(url="https://api.spotify.com/v1/me/player/queue", data=data, headers=header)
    ...
```

I've tried a lot of things but can't seem to understand why I'm getting Error 400 (Error 400: Required parameter uri missing).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

so the Spotify API for the [endpoint](https://developer.spotify.com/console/post-queue/) you're using suggests that the uri parameter required should be passed as part of the url, instead of as a `data` object.

Instead of `data = {'uri': uri}` can you please try adding your uri to the end of the url as such:

```
resp = requests.post(url="https://api.spotify.com/v1/me/player/queue?uri=?uri=spotify%3Atrack%3A5QO79kh1waicV47BqGRL3g", headers=header)
```

I also suggest using software like postman or insomnia to play around with the requests you send.

Comment: This worked like a charm and I'll accept this, thank you so much. In which cases would it be sufficient to pass the data like I originally thought? I passed it like that for a POST request to get access tokens; should I only do so when it explicitly says to pass it in the request's body?

Comment: Yes. I also suggest that you checkout Spotipy since you're using python. Cool library!